# Whats does ~~ mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been reading through some code and noticed a function:

```
    randint: function(n) {
        return ~~(Math.random() * n)
    }
```

I know ~ means "not" but how does ~~ change this return statement?

Comment: It's two NOT bitwise operators in a row

Comment: It's a way of forcing a numeric value to be "squeezed" into a 32-bit integer value.

Comment: It's a common way to draw a mustache ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"but how does ~~ change this return statement?"

Answer: It cuts all fractional digits.

`~~42.453754` -> `42`